# Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration . i use enableSessionstate true in web config

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis

Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <system.web><httpModules> section in the application configuration.
, i want to deploy project in local lan , in IIS . i follow all thing but this error is not resolving .

i add below code in web config but not work.

```
   <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="true" /> 
 </system.web>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrHYp.png)

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You try the below workaround to resolve the issue:

1.Removing and Re-adding the  in your web.config :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

2.Setting the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in the  element of your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

3.Run the below PowerShell command:

```
Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision
```